# iAd delegate is called in a different layer? - cocos2D-ios

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, iad

I have a Start_Up layer which my 1st layer when my game starts. I have added the iad delegate in it, so iads will be on top of all other layers. It is working fine so far but I am not sure if start_up iad delegate is called from other layers.. If not, what should I do? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your instance of `Start_Up` persists throughout the life of your app, the delegate methods will be called unless you explicitly unregister. For example, `Start_Up` will persist if it is prt of a scene that stays in the scenes stack of `CCDirector` because you pushed subsequent scenes onto it *and* you never remove the layer from your startup scene. In fact, even if your `Start_Up` layer does not exist anymore, the delegate methods will be called, and your app will crash.